# Getting error in token based authentication in python eve

Tags: python, authentication, jwt, eve

I am using token based authentication, to give access to my website API to logged users to access it.

I am getting following error.

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "Please provide proper credentials", "code": 401}}
```

I am storing username, password, email, token into my people schema.

```
    "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzAxMzg4NTQsInN1YiI6IjU1M2RlMjcwYmVkMDY5MTYwOWRiMWRkNyIsImV4cCI6MTQzMTM0ODQ1NH0.-H8m19tWeOgDXcem9pNjD3XXefMgGKv-ao3U8W9_P1U",

"username": <username>,
"password": <password>,
"email": <email>
```

I am encoding my token in the following way using

```
def create_token(user):
payload = {
    'sub': str(user['_id']),
    'iat': datetime.now(),
    'exp': datetime.now() + timedelta(days=14)
}

token = jwt.encode(payload, TOKEN_SECRET)
return token.decode('unicode_escape')
```

updating my return token into data base in following way after user successfully logged in

```
accounts = app.data.driver.db['people']
 accounts.update({'email': request.json['email']},{"$set":{'token':token}})
```

My Token authentication function shown below.

```
class TokenAuth(TokenAuth):
def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
    accounts = app.data.driver.db['people']
    return accounts.find_one({'token': token})
```

My TokenAuth included in the following way.

```
app = Eve(__name__,static_url_path='/static', auth=TokenAuth)
```

sending request using curl in following way

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzAxMzg4NTQsInN1YiI6IjU1M2RlMjcwYmVkMDY5MTYwOWRiMWRkNyIsImV4cCI6MTQzMTM0ODQ1NH0.-H8m19tWeOgDXcem9pNjD3XXefMgGKv-ao3U8W9_P1U"
```

getting following error

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "Please provide proper credentials", "code": 401}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem can be in:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzAxMzg4NTQsInN1YiI6IjU1M2RlMjcwYmVkMDY5MTYwOWRiMWRkNyIsImV4cCI6MTQzMTM0ODQ1NH0.-H8m19tWeOgDXcem9pNjD3XXefMgGKv-ao3U8W9_P1U"
```

Especially in:

```
-H "Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzAxMzg4NTQsInN1YiI6IjU1M2RlMjcwYmVkMDY5MTYwOWRiMWRkNyIsImV4cCI6MTQzMTM0ODQ1NH0.-H8m19tWeOgDXcem9pNjD3XXefMgGKv-ao3U8W9_P1U"
```

I think should be: Basic + base64(token+':')

I use this function in python :

```
def authorization(token):
    return 'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(token + ':'))

In [6]: token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MzAxMzg4NTQsInN1YiI6IjU1M2RlMjcwYmVkMDY5MTYwOWRiMWRkNyIsImV4cCI6MTQzMTM0ODQ1NH0.-H8m19tWeOgDXcem9pNjD3XXefMgGKv-ao3U8W9_P1U"

In [7]: print 'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(token + ':'))
Basic ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SnBZWFFpT2pFME16QXhNemc0TlRRc0luTjFZaUk2SWpVMU0yUmxNamN3WW1Wa01EWTVNVFl3T1dSaU1XUmtOeUlzSW1WNGNDSTZNVFF6TVRNME9EUTFOSDAuLUg4bTE5dFdlT2dEWGNlbTlwTmpEM1hYZWZNZ0dLdi1hbzNVOFc5X1AxVTo=
```

Ergo:

```
-H "Authorization: Basic ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SnBZWFFpT2pFME16QXhNemc0TlRRc0luTjFZaUk2SWpVMU0yUmxNamN3WW1Wa01EWTVNVFl3T1dSaU1XUmtOeUlzSW1WNGNDSTZNVFF6TVRNME9EUTFOSDAuLUg4bTE5dFdlT2dEWGNlbTlwTmpEM1hYZWZNZ0dLdi1hbzNVOFc5X1AxVTo="
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following url to get the Logged User id.

```
@app.route('/api/me')
@login_required
def me():
    return Response(json.dumps(g.user_id),  mimetype='application/json'
```

sending encrypted token to user by using following code.

```
def create_token(user):
payload = {
   'sub': str(user['_id']),
   'iat': datetime.now(),
   'exp': datetime.now() + timedelta(days=14)
}

  token = jwt.encode(payload, TOKEN_SECRET)
return token.decode('unicode_escape')
```

So My question is How to encrypt the token for above answer

```
  Basic base64.encode(token+':') format in my code
```

I am getting following error while doing following way

```
'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(token + ':'))
```

error is:

```
decoder error not enough segments for api/me url
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this two functions:

```
def headers(token, etag=False):
   headers = { 
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': authorization(token)
        }   
    if etag:
        headers['If-Match'] = etag
    return headers


def authorization(token):
    import base64
    return 'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(token + ':'))
```

This works for me

Comment: where I need to define these two functions and when i need to call them.

Comment: My server code is define in the following link [link] https://github.com/suryamuppalla/forsatya/blob/master/server.py

Comment: through curl your above answer is executing perfectly. In server how to receive token from front end,  I do not know exactly.

Comment: I use this functions to connect with the Eve server. With both I make de correct headers for the HTTP request